# A length of wire carries a steady current, is bent first to form a coil of 1 turn, same is bent with 3 turns.how their Resistance, voltage changes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrical-resistance

I want to know whether steady current means the current remains same or not.also in the above question how the current parameters changes between the two cases? In second case the radius becomes smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current is steady (i.e. DC), then there should be no change in the resistance (and therefore the voltage) for almost all cases. If you have AC current, then you will introduce an inductance by coiling the wire, which will introduce a voltage that opposes the change in current.

In extreme cases, if you bend the wire very tightly so that you're introducing a lot of stress, the wire will start to strech/deform and then you'll get a change in resistance - this is how a [strain gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge) operates.